# Hot-Swapping Java Classes

Tags: java

I've been working on a small Java-based online game, which, although not finished, I want to release it at some point. I don't forsee it being finished anytime soon, however, all that's missing are some continued story parts. I thought about patching updates into the game through the internet connection (as most games do) - but I wanted to be clever with it and use some form of class hot-swapping to patch in updates without having to re-load the game.

Originally, I thought that JRebel would work for this purpose, however, as far as I know, it's not easily invoked from within the application itself.

The way I envision this process is:

1. Server tells client that there's an update available
2. Client downloads ZIP/JAR/whatever and extracts it
3. Client loads in 'package class' which modifies the running image (Client has specially constructed parts of it designed to handle loading in additional classes & possibly overwriting existing classes.)
4. 'package class' handles overwriting of in-memory class representations.

The part that's troubling me is that if I have an object, i.e.

```
    //Something that's called when the app loads up
    CustomClass drawClass = new CustomClass();
    drawClass.setContext(Context.MAIN);
    //...More calls that set up drawClass
```

I want to be able to modify CustomClass and have it reflected in all instances of CustomClass. The only reason I am hopeful for this is that I could build in to each class a "copyMe" thing that essentially serializes it - which could be loaded into the new class.

Can I do this? If so, how?

Comment: this seems like something you'd want to look into: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html

Comment: Side note: when you have "remote" access to your JVM; then you could be using JRebel for it. I guess I wouldn't do it that way (but strive for a more "architected" way); but I think using JRebel could be working for you. (assuming that you are willing to pay the licence cost for your small online game)

Comment: JRebel is not for production use, and it doesn't reconstruct already constructed objects on class change, unless there is a plugin that keeps track of the relevant instances and is specifically wired to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might tackle some of the required functionality using [SPI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html)

In your code you can build a custom classloader that uses the implementation that is found using the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Although I think you need to find a custom serialization that you can reuse over these classes. For example you can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and serialize the interesting fields to `json`.  Newer implementations can deserialize and you got support for versioning etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're buying a world of hurt if you want to allow updates to arbitrary
parts of a running program.  I'm not saying it's impossibe, only that it's
very difficult to get right, especially considering missing or failed intermediate updates.

Instead, use the "suspend game/resume game" functionality, wrapped up so it's invisible to the user, to transition cleanly from the old version to the
updated version.